# Why gen_tcp is not defined in Erlang shell?

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell, gen-tcp

After I type `gen_` and then type a Tab in erlang shell, I get `gen_server`, `gen_event`, but I don't get a `gen_tcp`. How can I use `gen_tcp` in Erlang shell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A module has to be loaded in the node in order to show up in the autocompletion. So if you type l(gen_tcp). in the shell you will be able to use tab completion for gen_tcp.

Comment: That's cool. But I still have a question that why gen_tcp is not automaticly loaded when the node startup, just like gen_server? And, how can I find other not-auto-load-modules? Thanks.

Comment: @nicky_zs because gen_server is used already by the base system and gen_tcp is not (at least for your setup)

Comment: @nicky_zs For a list of the built-in modules that come with Erlang you should check the documentation at erlang.org. For anything else you should check their respective docs.

Comment: Thank you, PeerStritzinger and Lukas